# Unable to connect to redis running on docker from celery

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery, django-celery

I'm using the django application where i want to run celery workers. But when i hit `python -m celery -A cartpe worker`, i get the following error

```
consumer: Cannot connect to redis://redis:6379/0: Error 8 connecting to redis:6379. nodename nor servname provided, or not known..
```

This is my `celery.py` file

```
import os
from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cartpe.settings')

app = Celery('cartpe')

# Load the celery configuration from Django settings.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Discover asynchronous tasks in Django app modules.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

`__init__.py`

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

`settings.py`

```
# Celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0' # initially had 'redis://localhost:6379/0' which didn't work either
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

I have redis running in docker. Is this the reason i'm unable to connect to redis ? Also i'm using MacOs. I saw a number of solutions related to this but none worked. What can i do here to resolve the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with docker container where ports had be mentioned explicitly.
`docker run --name redis -d -p 6379:6379 redis:latest` and restarted celery and it worked.